# I want show JSON byte array to image and place it into img tag.

Tags: javascript, html, json

I got `json` string as like this: `["Teflon", Array(2926)]`

Array(2926) it is a image value how can I convert it into image
 and place it into `<img >` tag?

Comment: Well, without knowing how your Array (2926) exactly looks like, we can't give you any hints. - Since it seems that you're new here, I'd suggest to read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What kind of image value? Base 64 string? Can you add the value to your answer?

Comment: thank you for reply sir,i am new to this community.and i got the solution.i needd to convert it into base64 string in the service , and send it. even this solution i got from stackoverflow , thank to stackoverflow..